# Need Help in PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am studying about regex, i figured out some about matching one or more character, but i have a case, but don't know how to solve this..

For example i have:

```
$data = "bla bla -start- blu blu blu -end- bla bla";
$pattern = "/\-start\-[\w]\-end\- /";
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

i intend to take anything between '-start-' and '-end-', so i expect to get
' blu blu blu '.
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\w` represents only word characters, and you need to also allow for spaces.  Assuming you really want to allow anything in between `-start-` and `-end-` you can use `.` which matches any character.

Hyphens need not be escaped unless enclosed in a character pattern (between square brackets `[` and `]`), so you can replace `\-` with just `-`.

Just like using a single `\w` represents matching any *single* word character, `.` represents matching any *single* character, so you need to add some more information in.  Following either of these with `+` would indicate matching *at least one* character, or with a `*` would indicate *zero or more* characters.  Assuming you want at least one character, your expression should be okay like this:

```
$pattern = "/-start-(.+)-end- /";
```

Supposing you might encounter an expression like: `-start- foo -end- -end-` and you want to terminate on the first `-end-` (the content to extract is `foo`), then you need to operate in a non-greedy way.  PHP's regex is greedy by default, to turn this off, you follow the `+` (or a `*`) with a `?`, like this:

```
$pattern = "/-start-(.+?)-end- /";
```

Comment: Hyphens do not need to be escaped except in character classes. Your answer is otherwise spot-on.

Comment: @coreyward: I didn't think so and was checking -- ran a quick test and notably the escaping didn't break anything. Anyway, updated appropriately.

Comment: Although his question doesn't mention it, if between `-start-` and `-end-` there exists newline characters, you'd want to set the "dot-all" modifier of `s`. Therefore `$pattern = "% -start- (.+?) -end-  %six";` I also use the `x` modifier to keep readability with complex patterns, as it causes the engine to ignore whitespace (keep in mind you then need to add whitespace to the pattern if you wish to include it via `\s`) as well as the `i` modifier for case insensitivity.

Comment: wow, thank you very much, it works..
@coreyward: still thanks to you :D
@Tomcat: thanks Tom, Yeah, actually i need it to search on multiline string, your pattern using % and %six are new to me, can you explain it or give any referrences ?